# Controlling Spark Streaming of the Files

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark to read the text files from a folder and load them to hive.

The interval for the spark streaming is 1 min. The source folder may have 1000  files of bigger size in rare cases.

How do i control spark streaming to limit the number of files the program reads? Currently my program is reading all files generated in last 1 min. But i want to control the number of files it's reading.

I am using textFileStream API.

```
    JavaDStream<String> lines = jssc.textFileStream("C:/Users/abcd/files/");
```

Is there any way to control the file streaming rate?

Answer (score 1):

If your files are CSV files, you can use structured streaming to read the files into a streaming DataFrame with `maxFilesPerTrigger` like this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val streamDf = spark.readStream.option("maxFilesPerTrigger", "10").schema(StructType(Seq(StructField("some_field", StringType)))).csv("/directory/of/files")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid not. 
Spark steaming is based on **Time driven**. 
You can use **Flink** which provide **Data driven**

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/concepts/programming-model.html#windows

Answer (score 0):

You could use "spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled" and "spark.streaming.backpressure.initialRate" for controlling the rate at which data is received!!!

Comment: Isn't backpressure for Kakfa Streaming? Can you give me an example of doing this?

Comment: These are spark configs, evident from "spark.streaming.backpressure" name!!! It works perfectly with kafka. Other sources I have not tested.

Comment: spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition are the kind of configs specific to kafka.